# Mono : Is it possible to host a web/wcf service from console application?

Tags: linux, wcf, mono, centos, redhat

I know with .NET we can host wcf service from a console application without the need of webservers like IIS or apache. Is it possible to do the same with Mono 2.6.1 on a RHEL 5 or CentOS? Any links to any documentation will be highly helpful.

Comment: In what way is apache not a console application? What do you mean with 'console application'? I would understand console as in opposite to a GUI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This example](http://veritas-vos-liberabit.com/monogatari/2009/12/mono-wcf-advent-day-2-hello-wcf.html) looks like it's hosted from console application.

Comment: It really is hosted from the console.